# How to take the first derivative of the entropy-regularized Wasserstein distance?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, entropy, optimal-transport

In optimal transportation theory, it is better to regularize the Wasserstein distance with an entropy constraint because it is differentiable, unlike its unregularized counterpart. By being differentiable, it can then be treated as a loss function that is compatible with common optimization algorithms.

The entropy-regularized Wasserstein distance (aka Sinkhorn distance) is:
$$ \text{inf} _{\gamma \in \Pi } \sum \|x - y\| \enspace \gamma(x,y)- \epsilon H(\gamma)$$
where $H(\gamma) = -\sum \gamma \text{ log}(\gamma)$ is the Shannon entropy of the transport plan $\gamma$, and $\epsilon $ is the regularization parameter.

What then is the derivative of the above formula, could someone show how to derive it?

Answer (score 2):

This paper talks about the derivative of Sinkhorn distances https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2018/file/3fc2c60b5782f641f76bcefc39fb2392-Paper.pdf

Comment: which equation in the article gives the first derivative of the Sinkhorn distance? from what I can see, it only gives the differentials of the Sinkhorn algorithm's approximations. The Sinkhorn algorithm is not the same as the Sinkhorn distance

Comment: I think it is Theorem 3. If I understand correctly, your definition is same as $\tilde{S}_{\lambda} in the above paper.

Comment: Equation 13 in theorem 3 is unintelligible. It looks nothing like a differential equation since they wrapped it into a function called $P_T$. I don't know what that means